# I have two SELECTS in the same query - i need to make inner join between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is how my query looks:

```
DECLARE @month date
DECLARE @CustomerId int
DECLARE @InterfacedSystemId int

SET @month = '2013-05-01'
SET @CustomerId = 24
SET @InterfacedSystemId = 1

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,MisparHeshbonit) AS PreProcInvoiceNumber ,CONVERT(DATE,TaarichErech,103) AS PreProcDate , ROUND(sum(convert(float,SchumBruto)),2) AS PreProcSum  
FROM [VisaCalCredit] VCC
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,TaarichErech,103) BETWEEN @month AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@month))
      AND VCC.CustomerID = @CustomerID
GROUP BY MisparHeshbonit , CONVERT(DATE,TaarichErech,103)

) AS PreTable
ORDER BY PreProcInvoiceNumber, PreProcDate

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT InvoiceNumber AS PostProcInvoiceNumber,ActualPaymentTime AS PostProcDate ,ROUND(sum(GrossAmount),2) AS PostProcSum 
FROM [CreditAndDebit] C INNER JOIN [Transaction] T ON C.TransactionID = T.ID 
WHERE ActualPaymentTime BETWEEN @month AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@month))
      AND T.CustomerID = @CustomerId
      AND T.InterfacedSystemID = 1
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber , ActualPaymentTime

) AS PostTable
ORDER BY PostProcInvoiceNumber ,PostProcDate
```

I need to find the differences between the PreProcSum and the PostProcSum in those tables - and I cannot make inner join between the inner tables themselves (trigger other problems).

How can I make this inner join between those two tables i've defined in this query?

Comment: Can you please explain why you can't do an INNER JOIN between the tables? 'trigger other problems'

Comment: @BarakBenHorin : Is `PreProcInvoiceNumber` equal to `PostProcInvoiceNumber` ?

Comment: since there is duplications of records which cannot be avoided with DISTINCT.. (i've cleared that out with my manager )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your key is (InvoiceNumber, Date), I believe you can do this:

```
;WITH PreTable AS (
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(BIGINT,MisparHeshbonit) AS PreProcInvoiceNumber,
    CONVERT(DATE,TaarichErech,103) AS PreProcDate,
    ROUND(sum(convert(float,SchumBruto)),2) AS PreProcSum  
  FROM [VisaCalCredit] VCC
  WHERE 
    CONVERT(DATE,TaarichErech,103) BETWEEN @month AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@month))
    AND VCC.CustomerID = @CustomerID
  GROUP BY MisparHeshbonit, CONVERT(DATE,TaarichErech,103)
),
PostTable AS (
  SELECT 
    InvoiceNumber AS PostProcInvoiceNumber,
    ActualPaymentTime AS PostProcDate,
    ROUND(sum(GrossAmount),2) AS PostProcSum 
  FROM [CreditAndDebit] C INNER JOIN [Transaction] T ON C.TransactionID = T.ID 
  WHERE ActualPaymentTime BETWEEN @month AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@month))
    AND T.CustomerID = @CustomerId
    AND T.InterfacedSystemID = 1
  GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, ActualPaymentTime
),
MergedKeys AS (
  SELECT 
    PreProcInvoiceNumber AS InvoiceNumber,
    PreProcDate AS TheDate
  FROM PreTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    PostProcInvoiceNumber,
    PostProcDate
  FROM PostTable
)
SELECT *
FROM 
  MergedKeys mk
  LEFT JOIN PreTable prt
    ON prt.PreProcInvoiceNumber = mk.InvoiceNumber
    AND prt.PreProcDate= mk.TheDate
  LEFT JOIN PostTable pot
    ON pot.PostProcInvoiceNumber = mk.InvoiceNumber
    AND pot.PostProcDate= mk.TheDate
ORDER BY 
  mk.InvoiceNumber,
  mk.TheDate
```

Replace LEFT JOIN with JOIN if you are sure you will get all the invoice data in both of your selects.